# how to import file name / line numbers when using IDApython?

Tags: ida

When I use the UI of IDA to load a binary file with debug info, a window which prints "DWARF info found" will come out and I can choose "Import file names/line numbers" to present the correponding source lines of certain addresses.

However, I find when I using command line to run ida like "idat64 -A -S'script' binary_name", idat64 would not load the DWARF without specific setting.

I tried to find possible setting to load the DWARF infos but failed. Could someone help me solve this problem?

I want to use

```
ida_nalt.get_source_linnum
```

and

```
ida_lines.get_sourcefile
```

to export the address-to-line mapping informations.

However, without loading the DWARF info, running the scripts will only print invalid results.

Answer (score 0):

According to the config file in `cfg/dwarf.cfg` (which can be found in ida folder):

```
// Should the DWARF plugin import file names & line numbers information
// into the database?
// Can be overriden in the command line:
//      ida -Odwarf:import_lnnums=1 input_file
DWARF_IMPORT_LNNUMS = NO
```

Adding the option below can help.

```
-Odwarf:import_lnnums=1
```